# How to capture a photo from the webcam in the browser and save it in the server?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, webcam

I have seen this done by many websites, but I wonder how they do it. Some even allow one to crop the image. Is there a standard library or package for this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any library, because It could be done in several steps. I assume you are familiar with webcam and able to show signal from it in the `Video` object. If you don't, in short It reads as:

```
var video: Video = new Video();

addChild(video);

video.smoothing = true;
video.attachCamera(camera); //Camera reference
video.width = someWidth;
video.height = someHeight;
```

Because `Video` object implements `IBitmapDrawable` you can draw it in the Bitmap, and do whatever you want.

```
 var bitmapData : BitmapData = new BitmapData(_video.width, _video.height);

//Tada! You have screenshot of the current frame from video object
bitmapData.draw(cameraView);

//For testing, add as Bitmap
addChild(new Bitmap(bitmapData));
```

As for sending to the server, you need [some server-side implementation](http://nikohelle.net/2010/11/03/the-simplest-way-to-send-an-image-from-flash-to-php-without-user-interaction/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very usefull blog i came across (not mine)

http://matthewschrager.com/2013/05/25/how-to-take-webcam-pictures-from-browser-and-store-server-side/